# what is this format and how to read it in pandas

Tags: json, pandas

I have a file like this:

```
{"Name": "John", "age": 15}{"Name": "Anna", "age": 12}
```

they are on the same line.  What kind of format this file belongs to?
How to read it into pandas dataframe so that

```
name    age
John    15
Anna    12
```

Thanks!

Comment: [pandas.DataFrame.from_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html#pandas-dataframe-from-dict) you need parse json to list dict first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a supplement for @Raymond Kwok's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71060502/1518100). We don't need know the field names before converting the json to `DataFrame`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import re
# read file code same, so skip
js = '{"Name": "John", "age": 15}{"Name": "Anna", "age": 12}'
matches = re.findall(r'\{.+?}', js)
print(matches)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(matches)
print(df)
```

output:

```sh
['{"Name": "John", "age": 15}', '{"Name": "Anna", "age": 12}']
                             0
0  {"Name": "John", "age": 15}
1  {"Name": "Anna", "age": 12}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1 (use regex)**

In your case, you may read the content of your file using:

```
with open('file_path', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()
```

but in my test I will just assign `content` with your example line

```
content = '''{"Name": "John", "age": 15}{"Name": "Anna", "age": 12}'''
```

Then `re.findall` to extract the data into a list of tuples.

```
import re    
data = re.findall(r'{"Name": "([^"]*)", "age": (\d+)}', content)

print(data)
[('John', '15'), ('Anna', '12')]
```

Then build the dataframe with

```
pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'age'])
```

Note: `re.findall` attempts to find this pattern `{"Name": "([^"]*)", "age": (\d+)}` from `content`, and anything within the brackets `()` is extracted. `([^"]*)` is used for `Name` and means any length of string that does not include a `"` (so my assumption is that a name field never contains a `"`.  For `age`, `(\d+)` means any length (>=1) of digits.

**Approach 2 (use json)**

Another way is to make your `content` a json.

```
import json

pd.DataFrame(json.loads('[' + content.replace('}{"Name": ', '},{"Name": ') + ']'))
```

Comment: why not reg split each json and parse the json instead, this way the code is independent of specific fields.

Comment: that will work too!